# ¿Que tan seguro es VB.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, mysqlconnector

Antes que nada, un cordial saludo, mi cuestión es que quiero integrar una conexión a una base de datos **MySQL** desde el servidor de la pagina web del proyecto que estoy elaborando, pero a diferencia de **PHP** que es improbable que alguien pueda acceder a la contraseña, usuario, nombre y dirección del servidor de la base de datos, no estoy muy seguro que sea igual en **VB.net**, ya que tengo la preocupación de que alguien malintencionado, de alguna manera, pueda extraer el código y ver toda esa información, el proyecto lo estoy elaborando con el IDE Visual Studio, espero alguien pueda decirme si en **VB.net** no se puede hacer lo que anteriormente mencione, de ante mano, gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que es una aplicación web la que haces en VB.NET. A nivel de .NET podrías leer [Cadenas de conexión y archivos de configuración](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx). se basa en considerar la cadena de conexión en el archivo de configuración (como es web, se llama web.config), la manera de obtenerla y cifrar las secciones del archivo de configuración utilizando la herramienta `ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool`.

Comment: VB.net es tan seguro como tu lo hagas. Si tienes el mente la seguridad al hacer la aplicación, no vas a tener problemas. Ten en cuenta de todas maneras que ninguna aplicación es segura al 100%